# Trouble putting my apache server online

Tags: windows, apache-http-server, webserver, xampp

I'm trying to set up a server, I ended up choosing XAMPP, but I'm having lots of trouble to put my server online. I chose port 1234 to host the server, and when I run apache and access localhost:1234 it works normaly, but if I try to access it through my external IP it simply does not work! I have forwarded the ports on my router already, changed the apache httpd.conf to set up the ports and the IP, but I simply cannot access the server from outside my local network! I took a screenshot showing you that the port is indeed opened, the apache running and that everything should be working, but is not: http://s8.postimg.org/rbx0dpbqr/apache.jpg Sorry the Chrome error is in portuguese, but it's the default Chrome error when trying to access unexisting pages.

I don't know what I'm missing here, can you please help me? Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to access you external site via the external IP from inside the same LAN as the server? Have you tried from a computer that's actually outside your network?

Comment: Well, it actually worked! I had tried it yesterday, but it didn't work, but I changed WAMPSERVER for XAMPP and changed some configurations, but I kept on testing on my PC. Why can't I access it locally through my IP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your screenshot Apache it is working fine from outside your network, and indeed it did respond with a web page for me.  The webpage it responded with showed that I was not authorised to view the content and to modify "httpd-xampp.conf" - so definately Apache is working.

If you are trying to reach the server on its external IP address from your LAN, this most likely won't work as your router is not going to be doing the port translation - you might want to find another connection to try from, or set up a VPN or proxy on your PC to force you to go externally and come back again.

Comment: Yeah, I tried it with my cellphone and it worked, thanks!